# Magento 2 order stop generating after data migration

Tags: magento2, magento2-migration-tool

We used the Magento migration tool to migrate data from Magento 1 to Magento 2. Data migrated successfully but now order stop working. We checked the log and found that it stops working because of the below error.

```
Fatal Error: 'Uncaught TypeError: Argument 1 passed to Magento\Email\Model\Template::setVars() must be of the type array, null given
```

Any suggestions to solve this issue will be highly appreciated.

**Edited:**
We checked and found that this error is only coming when set "Separate Email" to "Send Order Email Copy Method" option under Admin > STORES > Configuration > SALES > Sales Email

Comment: With Magento version you use?

Comment: Magento CE 2.3.3

Comment: Have you use any custom email template?

Comment: No, we are using default email templates

Comment: Remove `var/generated` and clear cache and then check it.